# Can't append decoded string to list without it re-encoding the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, append

I'm really not sure how to phrase this question in the title I think just showing my code would speak for itself

```
import struct

thing1_to_pack = b'Hello World'
thing2_to_pack = 1982
thing3_to_pack = b'weeee123'

packed_thing = struct.pack('12si20s', 
  thing1_to_pack,
  thing2_to_pack,
  thing3_to_pack)

print(f'Packed thing is {packed_thing}\n')

unpacked_thing = struct.unpack('12si20s', packed_thing)

print(f'Unpacked thing is {unpacked_thing}\n')

listthing = []

for val in unpacked_thing:
  try:
    print(f'Adding {val.decode()} to the list\n')
    listthing.append(val.decode())
  except AttributeError as err:
    print(f'Adding {val} to the list\n')
    listthing.append(val)


print(f'Our final result is {listthing} !')
```

I expect the end result to be

```
['Hello World', 1982, 'weeee123']
```

However, what I end up with is

```
['Hello World\x00', 1982, 
'weeee123\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

I'm really unsure what to do, I know how I can get rid of the \x00s by reducing 12si20s to something like 11si8s, but the project I'm using this for will have varying sizes, and I need to be able to just strip them out...

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why not just strip the null characters from the result?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I could, but I'm very confused as to why what I am doing doesn't work. I would prefer to do it this way if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the following before your final `print`

```
listthing = [var.rstrip('\0')] for var in listthing]
```

This should remove all those pesky NULL bytes from the ends of your strings.